# Unable to run ActionMailer assertions within tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I can't figure out why I am unable to use the ActionMailer assertions within my tests. I generated a **Rails 5.2.1** application from scratch, scaffolded a model, and still get a NoMethodError when I call methods like `assert_emails`.

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "the truth" do
    assert_emails 0 do
      assert true
    end
  end
end
```

This raises an exception:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `assert_emails' for #<UserTest:0x007ff3ebeb58c0>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I can fix it by including it in my `test_helper.rb` but I'm not sure why I would have to:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include ActionMailer::TestHelper
  ...
end
```